# Window painting issue in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Tags: gnome, 18.04, graphics

It seems that windows don't repaint when I open a calculator, Bluefish or gEdit. It's impossible to use those applications.

example of the problem in Calculator 
[image: example of the problem in Calculator]

example of the problem in gEdit
[image: example of the problem in gEdit]

```
I have:
 - HP Compaq Elite 8300 Ultra-slim
 - CPU: Intel Core i5-3470S
 - Graphics: Intel Ivybridge Desktop with dual screen setup
 - Gnome: 3.28.2
 - Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
```

No 3rd party graphics drivers installed or found for this system.

Does anyone know what should I try to fix this problem?

Comment: This is still a relevant problem. I'm unable to use my Ubuntu because of this. Is there any clue what should I check to find the reason and try to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I managed to solve this problem.

I changed the input method from xim to ibus. Open im-config, click ok and after that you can change the input method.

More information here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1760818