# Software Updater: incorrect display while scrolling

Tags: 18.04, update-manager

When Software Updater pops up prompting me to install security updates, and I look at the "Technical Description" for one of the updates and scroll through the text, the window doesn't repaint properly:

[image: Text getting overwritten while scrolling]

The text doesn't get erased before being repainted after scrolling.

How can I get it not to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1099224/22015), apparently about the same problem, which led me to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1760818).  Apparently this is a problem with the Ambiance colour theme that appears for some users who have upgraded from an earlier Ubuntu version.  Changing the theme to Adwaita-dark in the Gnome Tweak Tool solved the problem:

[image: change theme in Gnome Tweak Tool]